# Generated PAT keys in Azure devops not showing up in overview

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Some service accounts were added in the collection and azure ad to generate PAT keys. However, the generated PATs don't show up in the overview under security. The PAT keys do work (tested to access the API), they just aren't visible in the overview.

Any ideas?

[image: No PATs in the overview]

Comment: i think its a bug, i observe same behaviour on some of my azure devops instances (maybe on all, i just didnt test it)

Comment: What user are you logged in as when looking at the overview? If the token generator is a different user, then you probably need to login as that user to see what it's been up to. Try closing all browsers and opening a private browser to signin with the new user.

Comment: Simply the same user that generates them

Comment: I'm having same issue. This happened when we changed the ownership from for AzureDevOps

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have a filter active ?

if you look in the top right corner you'll see the following:

[image: PAT filter options]

That could explain why you aren't seeing some of the token.

Comment: No, i set the filter to show everything. My own user shows my PAT keys, the other account can create one, and I can use it in a script, but they don't show up in the overview

Comment: Which overview are you using to view those tokens ?

Comment: The azure devops portal with the default ' /_usersSettings/tokens ' behind it.It works for my own account.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try clearing  Git credential manager for windows from below blog ,

https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/master/Docs/Faq.md#q-why-is-gitexe-failing-to-authenticate-after-linkingunlinking-your-visual-studio-team-services-organization-from-azure-active-directory

As a workaround try creating the new organization in your Azure DevOps org and these will be visible to you.

This worked for me.